# Creating a given matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How can I construct this matrix in R by for (loop)?

```
{[1000,100][1000,200][1000,300][2000,100][2000,200][2000,300][3000,100][3000,200][3000,300]};
```

Comment: does  the answer have to use a `for` loop? (if so, why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting from the *string* itself (and cannot generate it as Ben and Rui have discussed), then you can try parsing it:

```r
txt <- '{[1000,100][1000,200][1000,300][2000,100][2000,200][2000,300][3000,100][3000,200][3000,300]};'
m <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(txt, "[^,0-9]+")[[1]], ","))
m
#       [,1]   [,2] 
#  [1,] "1000" "100"
#  [2,] "1000" "200"
#  [3,] "1000" "300"
#  [4,] "2000" "100"
#  [5,] "2000" "200"
#  [6,] "2000" "300"
#  [7,] "3000" "100"
#  [8,] "3000" "200"
#  [9,] "3000" "300"
```

Then convert to `numeric` with:

```r
m <- apply(m, 2, as.numeric)
m
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,] 1000  100
#  [2,] 1000  200
#  [3,] 1000  300
#  [4,] 2000  100
#  [5,] 2000  200
#  [6,] 2000  300
#  [7,] 3000  100
#  [8,] 3000  200
#  [9,] 3000  300
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- expand.grid((1:3)*100,(1:3)*1000)  ## construct data frame of all combinations
as.matrix(x[2:1])                       ## reverse column order, convert to matrix
```

Your use case really isn't clear to me, but I'll just point out that if you're doing this from scratch (i.e. you're going to be entering values manually), then here's the appropriate syntax (whitespace/newlines are optional, for clarity):

```
matrix(byrow=TRUE, ncol=2,
       c(1000,100,
         1000,200,
         1000,300,
         2000,100,
         2000,200,
         2000,300,
         3000,100,
         3000,200,
         3000,300))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But I put 1000 first, `expand.grid((1:3)*1000,(1:3)*100)`.

Comment: doesn't that generate rows in the wrong order (OP's example has the thousands column varying slower than the hundreds column)?  (I kind of wish that `expand.grid` had an option to control order of speed in columns ...)